Use S3 as Context Root Directory for Great Expectations Data Validation
I am new to using Great Expectations and having some trouble setting things up.
I am looking for a way to create the 'gx' directory (gx context) and all the contents inside it that get created when creating the context, to s3.
I tried using the following code, but this creates a folder called 's3a:' in my local directory (from where the code is running), instead of creating the context in s3:
context = gx.get_context(context_root_dir="s3a://<my-bucket>/my-prefix")
Note that I can access my s3 bucket contents using boto3 from the same environment.
